# Check the type of all elements in a list of list in and that their numerical value falls within a range

Tags: python, loops

I want to loop over each element and check if its type is `int` and if it lays within range of `12 <= i <= 20`
if so return `True`

I use `any` to return if all elements are correct and `isinstance` to catch the type of each element.

The function gives me no output and no bug report so I don't know where the error is.

```
listoflist = [[14,13,13,14]]

def list_check(my_list):
    if all(isinstance(i, int) and 12 <= i <= 20 for i in my_list):
        print("true")
        return True
```

Comment: Your passing nested list, try ``list_check([[14,13,13,14]][0])``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you're looping through a one element list, so basically the `for i in my_list` only has one resulting item: `[14,13,13,14]`

You will need to select `list[0]` to iterate through the inner elements. There are also more elegant solutions than using for loops to apply such simple operations on lists, for instance `map()` and `lambda`:

```
listoflist = [[14,13,13,14]]

def list_check(mylist):
    f = lambda x: isinstance(x, int) and 12 <= x <= 20
    return all(map(f, mylist[0]))
```

```
list_check(listoflist)
```

```
Out[55]: True
```

`lambda` creates a "callable" function, and `map` applies this function to all elements of an iterable (e.g., list).

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that you use nested list. Also you do not get any output whatsoever because you are not calling the function.Following code prints True on console

```
my_list = [14,13,13,14]

def list_check(my_list):

    if all(isinstance(i, int) and 12 <= i <= 20 for i in my_list):
        print("true")
        return True
list_check(my_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your case because you have list in list:

```
listoflist = [14,13,13,14]


def list_check(my_list):
    if all(isinstance(i, int) and 12 <= i <= 20 for i in my_list):
        print("true")
        return True

print(list_check(listoflist))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```py
def list_check(my_list_of_lists):
    for my_list in my_list_of_lists:
        if all([isinstance(i, int) and 12 <= i <= 20 for i in my_list]):
            print("true")
            return True
```

Its not clear that you want it always to use list of lists as you post in your example. Or if you want the output to be true if all the lists are true. This will output true as many times as there are lists that fulfill the condition.